# SQL Server running balance with Partition by month

Tags: sql, sql-server, window-functions

I have the following scenario where a user has some allowance taken every month up to a yearly capping.

I have successfully implemented this as shown [here](http://rextester.com/WGEUWN1594)

I have stumbled into a problem for if the user gets promoted during the year the yearly capping needs to be ratified accordingly.

The following query gave these results. (Using sql server 2012)

```
SELECT *,
       RemainingBalance = AnnualCapping - Sum(amount)
                                            OVER (
                                              partition BY userid, year, annualcapping
                                              ORDER BY userid, year, month)
FROM   exampleTx
WHERE  userid = 1
       AND year = 2015
```

data

```
userId  year    month   monthname   name    surname annualCapping   amount  RemainingBalance
1       2015    1       January     Joe     Black   500,00          40,00    460,00
1       2015    2       February    Joe     Black   500,00          40,00    420,00
1       2015    3       March       Joe     Black   500,00          40,00    380,00
1       2015    4       April       Joe     Black   500,00          40,00    340,00
1       2015    5       May         Joe     Black   500,00          40,00    300,00
1       2015    6       June        Joe     Black   500,00          40,00    260,00
1       2015    7       July        Joe     Black   500,00          40,00    220,00
1       2015    8       August      Joe     Black   500,00          40,00    180,00
1       2015    9       September   Joe     Black   1000,00         40,00    **960,00**  
1       2015    10      October     Joe     Black   1000,00         40,00    **920,00**
1       2015    11      November    Joe     Black   1000,00         40,00    **880,00**
1       2015    12      December    Joe     Black   1000,00         40,00    **840,00**
```

In September the monthly allowance should have been proportional to remaining of year.

```
4 months = 1000 * 4/12 = 333.33
```

and remaining balance of `293.33, 253.33, 213.33,173.33`.

Could I achieve this without modifying the annual capping field. ie.e would have been simpler if annual capping was reduced to `333.33` but this is the data I have.

A change in capping of previous month would indicate a promotion has taken place. It can occur during any month. Hence the new capping should be proportional.

Comment: how do you identify when a user gets promoted? is that info in a different table? and is the rule same for all the users?

Comment: The annual capping is added to signal a promotion in this example. It is actually coming from another table. The sql file shared contains a simple example that can work with. Same rule for same users,

Comment: Will it be always last four months have proportional calc?

Comment: Check if this is ok for you http://rextester.com/BZC12451

Comment: Updated: A change in capping of previous month would indicate a promotion has taken place. It can occur during any month. Hence the new capping should be proportional .     Why the minus vote???

Answer (score 0):

You could use following query

```
Select *,
RemainingBalance = AnnualCapping - SUM(amount) OVER (
partition  by userid ,year ORDER BY userid, year,month) 
 from
 exampleTx
 where userid = 1 and year = 2015
```

Remove the Annual Capping from the Partition by clause.